# twilio 'Unknown context accounts

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to send a simple SMS via Twilio with Php, but i get this Fatal error,

> Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException' with message
>   'Unknown context accounts' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\vendor\twilio\sdk\Twilio\Rest\Client.php:687
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\twilio.php(24): Twilio\Rest\Client->__call('accounts', Array)
>
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\twilio.php(24): Twilio\Rest\Client->accounts('AC8687f4eaba8c6...')
>
> 2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Twilio\vendor\twilio\sdk\Twilio\Rest\Client.php on
>   line 687

This is my local server code:

```
<?php 
    // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install 
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library 
    use Twilio\Rest\Client; 
    $account_sid = 'AC8687f4eaba8c68XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
    $auth_token = '6baf210351f27a38850XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
    $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token); 
    $messages = $client->accounts('AC8687f4eaXXXXXXXXXXX') 
    ->messages->create('+52722XXXXXXX', array( 
         'From' => '+151240XXXXX',        
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks as though you are trying to send a message from the account you authorised the PHP library with in the first place. In this case, you do not need to call to the accounts resource first. It may have been an intentional omission, but I also notice your message doesn't have a body.

The following code should work for you:

```
<?php 
    // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install 
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library 
    use Twilio\Rest\Client; 
    $account_sid = 'AC8687f4eaba8c68XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
    $auth_token = '6baf210351f27a38850XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
    $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token); 
    $messages = $client->messages->create('+52722XXXXXXX', array( 
         'From' => '+151240XXXXX',
         'Body' => 'Hello from my PHP code!'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: Just came here with the same issue, looks like we both copy-pasted the Twilio sample PHP code from here https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/getting-started/build which is broken and causes this exception...

Comment: Hi folks! Twilio dev here . That code sample in our console is indeed incorrect - we're going to fix it ASAP. The one @philnash dropped here should work for you. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @AndrewTorkBaker FYI, the code sample still appears to be incorrect

Comment: @AndrewTorkBaker *still* broken. No way to copy/paste and use the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$twilio = new Client(config('services.twilio.sid'), config('services.twilio.token'));

$message = $twilio->messages->create(
    '+1234567890', // The recipient's phone number
    [
        'from' => config('services.twilio.from'),
        'body' => 'Hello from Twilio!', // The SMS message content
    ]
);

// Check the response or handle any errors
dd($message->sid);
```